# How to hide specific parts of a grid?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

What i want to do is to create, and make all the grid existing, but hide a part of it. It might looks a bit confusing, but let me explain:

[image]

Here is a grid with 4 rows, and 182 columns. It shows a half of a year in days, and for an example processes of projects. What i want to earn is, to show just a specific part (in the example the days of the fourth month) of a grid but in the way that the hidden parts are just hidden, but they remain existing. To the better understanding, the result i want is something like this: show the grid's columns from 120 to 150, and rows from 1 to 4, so make only this area visible from the grid.

Comment: Hi, please add the HTML and CSS you have tried so far. Thanks

Comment: My code was written in react, and has a length (just the grid) of 300 lines, that's why i didn't attached it. What i was tried is to calculate the place of the elements, and just show them in the interval of the month's days. But because the months are following each other, and the processes too, i don't want to cut them depending on the end, and start of the months, and calculate where i need to cut them, it will be much better if all of the processes are in the grid, but i can just cover them without cutting or something else

Comment: It is very unclear what you’re asking here. Please add some code and elaborate clearly on your question

Answer (score 1):

You can cover both sides of your grid container with its 2 :pseudos, absolutely positioned.

➡️ [Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/xzKpPm?editors=0100)

[Good start about Grid layout on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 5rem);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(25, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.25rem;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
}

.container::before {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / -1 / span 8;
}

.container::after {
  grid-area: 1 / 13 / -1 / -1;
}
```